# Idiomatic use of `Option` and `unwrap` in mean, median and mode Rust program for Chapter 8 of The Book

Tags: beginner, reinventing-the-wheel, rust

I've recently finished Chapter 8 of The Book and have started doing the exercises at the end of the chapter. This post pertains to the first exercise which involves writing a program to output the averages of a list of integers. I thought the instructions for this particular exercise was a bit vague, so I tried to make it simple by not including REPL functionality in my implementation. Anyway, here's my current solution:

```rust
// Given a list of integers, use a vector and return the mean (the average
// value), median (when sorted, the value in the middle position), and
// mode (the value that occurs most often; a hash map will be helpful
// here) of the list.

use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Averages {
  mean: f64,
  median: f64,
  mode: Vec<i32>
}

fn sum(vector: &Vec<i32>) -> Option<i32> {
  match vector.len() {
    0 => None,
    _ => {
      let mut accumulator = 0;

      for element in vector {
        accumulator += element;
      }

      Some(accumulator)
    }
  }
}

fn mean(vector: &Vec<i32>) -> Option<f64> {
  match vector.len() {
    0 => None,
    length =>
      Some((sum(vector).unwrap() as f64) / (length as f64))
  }
}

fn is_even(number: &usize) -> bool {
  number % 2 == 0
}

fn median(vector_original: &Vec<i32>) -> Option<f64> {
  match vector_original.len() {
    0 => None,
    length => {
      let mut vector_cloned = vector_original.to_vec();

      vector_cloned.sort_unstable();
      match is_even(&length) {
        true => {
          let length_halved = length / 2;

          Some(((
            &vector_cloned[length_halved - 1] +
            &vector_cloned[length_halved]) as f64) / 2.0)
        },
        false =>
          Some(vector_cloned[((
            (length as f64) /
            2.0).floor() as usize)] as f64)
      }
    }
  }
}

fn mode(vector: &Vec<i32>) -> Option<Vec<i32>> {
  match vector.len() {
    0 => None,
    _ => {
      let mut counts = HashMap::new();

      for number in vector {
        let count = counts.entry(number).or_insert(1u32);
        *count += 1u32;
      }

      let mut max_count = 0;

      for count in counts.values() {
        if count > &max_count {
          max_count = *count;
        }
      }

      let mut modes: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();

      for (number, count) in &counts {
        if count == &max_count {
          modes.push(**number);
        }
      }

      Some(modes)
    }
  }
}

fn get_averages(vector: &Vec<i32>) -> Option<Averages> {
  match vector.len() {
    0 => None,
    _ => Some(
      Averages {
        mean: mean(vector).unwrap(),
        median: median(vector).unwrap(),
        mode: mode(vector).unwrap()
      }
    )
  }
}

fn print_averages(vector: &Vec<i32>) {
  match vector.len() {
    0 => println!("Vector is empty."),
    _ => {
      let averages: Averages = get_averages(vector).unwrap();

      println!(
"Mean: {}
Median: {}
Mode(s): {:?}",
        &averages.mean,
        &averages.median,
        &averages.mode
      );
    }
  }
}

fn main() {
  print_averages(&(10..=20).collect());
  print_averages(&vec![5,5,5,4,3,2,1,1,1]);
  print_averages(&vec![]);
}
```

I wrote the current implementation like I did as I was trying to write it such that each of the functions are reusable independent of each other and in contexts possibly outside of this particular program (hence the arguably redundant calls to `len`). But now I'm wondering if using so many `unwrap`s like I did is the idiomatic way to handle the `Option`s or if there's a better way to have written this instead. I'm especially worried that my implementation might be brittle because I encountered a couple of panics when I was writing and testing it.

I'm also unsure if I'm doing borrowing and moving, as well as referencing and dereferencing optimally, especially in the `mode` function; despite it working properly, I'm a little confused
as to what's its actually doing with the data and references, so some explanation about it would be really welcome.

Any other constructive criticisms in general are also welcome, so please nitpick to your hearts content!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read [6005's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/255706/188857) first — the most important issues are
covered there.  Here are some additions:

## Formatting

`rustfmt` formats your code according to the official [Rust Style
Guide](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/tree/master/style-guide), which most Rustaceans are familiar with, to ease
communication.

## Argument passing

As 6005 pointed out, make your parameters `&[i32]` instead of
`Vec<i32>`.  See [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a
`String` (`&String`), `Vec` (`&Vec`), or `Box` (`&Box`) as a function
argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/9716597)

There is an exception: for `median`, you clone the numbers and sort
the clone.  If the caller has a disposable collection that will not
be used after calculating the median, this would be wasteful.  I
suggest taking a `Vec` by value here:

```rust
fn median(mut numbers: Vec<i32>) -> Option<f64> {
    // ...
    numbers.sort_unstable();
    // ...
}
```

For `Copy` types like `usize`, there is no need to take a reference.
Simply pass the `usize` instead.

## `mean`

Since your `sum` checks for empty collections already, you can use the
result rather than check again in `mean`:

```rust
fn mean(numbers: &[i32]) -> Option<f64> {
    (sum(vector)? as f64) / (numbers.len() as f64)
}
```

where the [`?` operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#a-shortcut-for-propagating-errors-the--operator) automatically unwraps the `Option` if it
is `Some` and returns `None` from the enclosing function otherwise.

## Arithmetic

This is an unnecessary use of floating point arithmetic:

```rust
(((length as f64) / 2.0).floor() as usize)
```

Integer division rounds toward zero, so what you want is simply
`length / 2`.

## `None` vs `NaN`

Since you're already returning `f64` for `mean` and `median`, an
alternative to using `Option` might be to simply return `f64::NAN`
when the collection is empty, as proper `f64` arithmetic should be
`NAN`-aware anyway.  `None` and `NAN` both have their pros and cons.
Personally, I like to use `NAN` to simplify the type, but the decision
is up to you.

## Control flow

In `median`, too many levels of indentation make the code less
readable.  The `match`es can be eliminated using `if` and `return`.

Combining the previous points, here's roughly how I would write
`median`:

```rust
fn median(numbers: Vec<i32>) -> f64 {
    let length = numbers.len();

    if length == 0 {
        return f64::NAN;
    }

    numbers.sort_unstable();

    if is_even(length) {
        let left = numbers[length / 2];
        let right = numbers[length / 2 + 1];

        (left as f64 + right as f64) / 2.0
    } else {
        numbers[length / 2] as f64
    }
}
```

which hopefully looks simpler.

## `mode`

`usize` should be a more natural choice for the value type of the map.

There are some functionalities from the standard library that you can
use to simplify the code, including [`max`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.max), [`filter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter), and
[`map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map):

```rust
fn mode(numbers: &[i32]) -> Option<Vec<i32>> {
    let freqs = HashMap::<i32, usize>::new();

    for number in numbers {
        freqs.entry(number).or_insert(0) += 1;
    }

    let max_count = freqs.values().max()?;
    let mode = freqs
        .iter()
        .filter(|(_, &count)| count == max_count)
        .map(|(&number, _)| number)
        .collect();
    Some(mode)
}
```

## `get_averages` & `print_averages`

Empty collections aren't common — I wouldn't waste two branches
on them.  Simply let the code run through:

```rust
fn get_averages(numbers: Vec<i32>) -> Option<Averages> {
    Some(Averages {
        mean: mean(vector)?,
        median: median(vector)?,
        mode: mode(vector)?,
    })
}
```

The same applies to `print_averages` — you're wasting three
branches in total for non-empty collections.  Personally, I think the
multiline string literal disrupts the aesthetics of the code, so I
got:

```rust
fn print_averages(numbers: Vec<i32>) {
    match get_averages(numbers) {
        None => println!("Empty collection"),
        Some(Average { mean, median, mode }) => {
            println!("Mean: {}", mean);
            println!("Median: {}", median);
            println!("Modes: {:?}", mode);
        }
    };
}
```

## Doc comments & tests

As a bonus, you can add [doc comments](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-02-publishing-to-crates-io.html#making-useful-documentation-comments) and [tests](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-00-testing.html) to document
your code if you have spare time.

Comment: Good answer, nice use of `?` which I didn't touch on

Comment: @6005 It seems that we are the only active Rust reviewers now.  Let's keep up the good work :)

Answer (score 8):

Good job in separating what you did into self-contained functions. Some comments on design and style:

- First things first: always run Clippy! (`cargo clippy`) Its feedback is usually helpful. Here it notices a few problems:

  - Whenever you have a function with `&Vec<T>` as an argument, it should almost always be rewritten as taking a slice `&[T]`. Think of a slice as a more general vector-like memory, so a function which accepts `&[T]` is more general than one that accepts `&Vec<T>`. This also has the side effect of changing your main function a bit:

    ```
        fn main() {
            let v: Vec<i32> = (10..=20).collect();
            print_averages(&v);
            print_averages(&[5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1]);
            print_averages(&[]);
        }
    ```
  - In the line `((&vector_cloned[length_halved - 1] + &vector_cloned[length_halved])`, you can remove both ampersands.
- In your `sum` function, returning `0` for the sum of an empty list (so, `fn sum(vector: &[i32]) -> i32`) is cleaner and more standard. Also, there is a built-in for this function: `vector.iter().sum()`
- Your `mean` function is clear, the use of `match vector.len()` is clever (the alternative is `if vector.is_empty() {`, but then you still have to call `.len()` again in the else branch. So I like your design choice better.)
- However in contrast, in `mode` and `print_averages`, here it is clearer to use `if vector.is_empty() {` since you aren't using the length in the logic.
- Relatedly, in `median` when you use `match is_even(&length)`, here I think it is clearer to use an if statement, since there is no value associated with one of the match branches that you need access to.
- Also in `median` I think some of the logic can be clearer using intermediate variables instead of complex expressions. In particular:

  ```
              let ele1 = vector_cloned[length_halved - 1];
              let ele2 = vector_cloned[length_halved];
              Some(((ele1 + ele2) as f64) / 2.0)
  ```

To answer your specific questions:

> But now I'm wondering if using so many unwraps like I did is the idiomatic way to handle the Options or if there's a better way to have written this instead. I'm especially worried that my implementation might be brittle because I encountered a couple of panics when I was writing and testing it.

Using `unwraps` here is actually pretty justified: you statically know that these vectors are nonempty so your `unwrap`s should never panic. You are right to be concerned though as normally `unwrap`s are best avoided. If you prefer you can do `.expect("unreachable")` to indicate what exactly went wrong.

> I'm also unsure if I'm doing borrowing and moving, as well as referencing and dereferencing optimally, especially in the mode function.

Edited to add: some comments on the mode function:

Some improvements to your use of references:

- You created a `HashMap<&i32, u32>`; this leads to some weird dereferencing in the code. It would be better to create a `HashMap<i32, u32>`. You can make sure you are doing it correctly by using a type annotation: `let mut counts: HashMap<i32, u32> = HashMap::new();`
- For the first for loop, you can use `.and_modify` to simplify the logic: (note vector is a reference / slice):

```
            let mut counts: HashMap<i32, u32> = HashMap::new();

            for &number in vector {
                counts.entry(number).and_modify(|count| *count += 1).or_insert(1u32);
            }
```

- The second for loop can be avoided using `.max()` directly on iterators:

`let max_count: u32 = *counts.values().max().unwrap()`

- Once you have a `HashMap<i32, u32>`, the third for loop becomes much nicer. You can avoid references completely by consuming the hashmap in the for loop:

```
            for (number, count) in counts {
                if count == max_count {
                    modes.push(number);
                }
            }
```

But the most common way is to iterate by reference, which would normally be written this way:

```
            for (&number, &count) in &counts {
                if count == max_count {
                    modes.push(number);
                }
            }
```

Or equivalently if you prefer:

```
            for (number, count) in &counts {
                if *count == max_count {
                    modes.push(*number);
                }
            }
```

- You can also do the last loop with a filter instead of an explicit for loop, though when learning it's always good to write out for loops for practice.
- Also for larger projects, ultimately the best way to do this would probably be to use a dedicated multiset collection, for instance the `multiset` crate. The mode body should be really pretty short, like `let counts: MultiSet<i32> = vector.collect(); counts.iter().max_by_key(...)`.